# Stata: Call a do file containing loop from a program in the other do file

Tags: loops, stata

I am trying to call a do file which has loops from a program in other do file. I am getting an error.
Now, if I use `do` instead of `include`, it runs fine but I don't get to use local macros created. I used `include` so I can use the macros further in the program. I don't want to use `global`.

First do file (test.do).

```
forval i = 1/5 {
    local val`i' = `i'
}
```

Second do file(call-test.do)

```
capture program drop test
program test

include "test.do" 

di `val1'
end

test
```

I got error `r(9611);`

I using version 16.1

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error. The 9XXX codes are for major system errors in Stata. Stata's documentation says: "9xxx. Various messages, all indicating an unexpected system failure. You should never see such a message. If one occurs,
save your data, and exit Stata immediately. Please email tech-support@stata.com to report the problem."

Answer (score 1):

Response from Stata support

> The -include- is designed to let you share definitions. It will not
> work correctly within a program as documented in -help include-
>
> The short answer is that -include- is usually ok to use in programs,
> but not with looping commands, and if you use -include- in a program,
> it probably isn't working the way you think it is.
>
> Here's the long version of exactly what is going on:
>
> When you use -include- in a program, your program literally includes
> the -include- command in it.  The program does NOT have the contents
> of the include file substituted in place.  That's the start of the
> problem for looping commands.
>
> In any case, when a program executes the -include- command, Stata gets
> confused about whether to define a loop program on the behalf of a
> looping command globally or within the program, and things go downhill
> from there.  Given how the code is structured, it is unlikely we could
> fix -include- to behave differently, so our documentation really
> should simply recommend against using -include- in programs.  In
> addition, at the point at which the failure occurs, Stata simply knows
> that it cannot call a program that it thinks should already be in
> memory, hence the 9611 return code.  It has no idea at that point that
> this was because it was called with -include-, unfortunately.
>
> We could in the future introduce a true C-like "#include" for use in
> programs which would simply substitute in-line the lines from whatever
> was included into your program